# Can I limit this meta box to a particular page?

Tags: dashboard, metabox

I am using a version of this (http://www.deluxeblogtips.com/meta-box-script-for-wordpress/) meta box script but I want to be able to limit which edit screen a meta box shows.

For example, if I only want a meta box to show in the "contact" page edit screen, is that possible?

```
$meta_boxes[] = array(
'id' => 'project-box-1',                            // meta box id, unique per meta box
'title' => 'Project Box 1',         // meta box title
'pages' => array('page'),   // post types, accept custom post types as well, default is array('post'); optional
'context' => 'normal',                      // where the meta box appear: normal (default), advanced, side; optional
'priority' => 'high',                       // order of meta box: high (default), low; optional
```

Comment: Just add `var_dump($_REQUEST);` in some function that gets loaded on admin_head or similar. This way you can see what the exact request is. Btw: Care about your open Qs. 25% accept rate is too low for most ppl to give real answers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Inside your `add_meta_boxex` hook callback function, you will have an `add_meta_box()` call. Wrap that call in a conditional, using data from the `$post` global (I'm *fairly certain* it is available in `edit.php`). For example, you could use either the Page ID or slug.

Page ID:

```
global $post;
if ( '123' == $post->ID ) {
    // Page has ID of 123, add meta box
    add_meta_box( $args );
}
```

Page slug:

```
global $post;
$slug = basename( get_permalink( $post->ID ) );
if ( 'contact' == $slug ) {
    // Page has ID of 123, add meta box
    add_meta_box( $args );
}
```

Note: you can also target the edit.php page, using the `$pagenow` global, e.g.:

```
global $pagenow, $page;
if ( 'edit.php' = $pagenow && '123' == $post->ID ) {
    add_meta_box( $args );
}
```

However, it might be more efficient just to target the appropriate `add_meta_boxes` hook for your callback. For example, your `add_action()` call probably looks like this:

```
add_action( 'add_meta_boxes', 'callback_function_name' );
```

But, you could instead use the [`add_meta_boxes_{post_type}`](http://adambrown.info/p/wp_hooks/hook/add_meta_boxes_%7B%24post_type%7D) hook, to target Pages specifically:

```
add_action( 'add_meta_boxes_page', 'callback_function_name' );
```

That way, the callback only gets called in the Page post-type context.

Answer (score 1):

See I tend to think a little different than developers.  I would make a custom template and associate this with just that template.  This way it exists and if you want to add it to another page you use the new custom template.

I don't have the code in front of me right now.

Comment: It depends on the nature of the content being added via meta box. But if it requires user input of data (text, etc.), rather than merely a checkbox or select, then those data have to be *input* somewhere, either as Post Custom Meta, or else as a Theme Option.

Comment: @Chris - Do you still have this script that you mentioned??? Your idea is exactly what Ive been after for some time now with no avail. Targeting the use of a specific template makes so much more sense to me as well.

Comment: @Mr.Brown - I don't have control of the site where I had something like that set-up.  I believe we used advanced custom fields for the input.  I believe we used the approach suggested on http://advancedcustomfields.com/support/discussion/34/advanced-custom-fields-show-up-on-all-edit-pages/p1

Comment: @ChipBennett - sorry I didn't respond sooner.  I understand that, but selecting individual pages by ID or global all posts or pages - doesn't seem like a good idea.  I much prefer a customized set-up with either page templates or custom posts for any customized content types.