# Meta Box Only in CPT Edit Page, Not in Add New

Tags: custom-post-types, metabox, post-meta

I have a CTP named `leads` and have 2 metaboxes added to the CPT new/edit screen. I need to have one of them only in edit screen, not in add new.

Played with the codes provided in couple of answers, but they weren't of much help. ([97845](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/97845/is-there-a-way-to-submit-only-meta-box-content-in-post-edit-page) and [89395](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/89395/possible-to-add-meta-box-to-edit-php-pages))

Can anyone help? I don't necessarily want anyone to do it for me, but a few playable starts would be great.

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Check the `action` of the [current screen](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_current_screen) object for `add`:

```
function wpd_add_meta_box() {
    $screen = get_current_screen();
    if( 'add' != $screen->action ){
        add_meta_box(
            'myplugin_sectionid',
            'My meta box',
            'myplugin_meta_box_callback',
            'leads'
        );
    }
}
add_action( 'add_meta_boxes', 'wpd_add_meta_box' );
```